# HOw to create Jira using Rest API and add users in notification

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am looking for a way to create a Jira using Rest API and in that create issue json i should be able to add users to be notified"

i tried adding the cc:users it did not work for me. Is tha cc field exposed using api ? anyother way to do it ?

Comment: anyone who can help with this .  The requirement is to creata Jira defect using rest api and have multiple watchers in that defect.